# Server side authentication for Google Analytics API in PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I want an automated process that requests some data from the analytics api and save it to my own database.

But in the Hello Analytics toutorial was only the client side oauth mentioned.

So I would like to know if and how it's possible to have a Server Side authentication for the Analytics API v4.

Thanks :).

Comment: Sure. Here's the instructions for authentication: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization You want the information on Service Accounts, which do not need interactive authorization once the keys are set up.

Comment: thanks :) I will give it a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use service accounts with the Google analytics reporting api v4.  You can use  [Hello Analytics Reporting API v4; PHP quickstart for service accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php)

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$response = getReport($analytics);
printResults($response);


/**
 * Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 *
 * @return An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 */
function initializeAnalytics()
{

  // Use the developers console and download your service account
  // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
  // change the key file location if necessary.
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';

  // Create and configure a new client object.
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

  return $analytics;
}


/**
 * Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
 *
 * @param service An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 * @return The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}


/**
 * Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 *
 * @param An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function printResults($reports) {
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
    $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
    $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

    for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
      $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
      $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
      $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
        print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
      }

      for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
        $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
          $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
          print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great Way but this does not fix my Problem. I dont want any authentication or sign in with google. But with this Code it still redirects me and let me choose a account to sign in with.

Comment: Then you are using the wrong code look again.  This form of authorization will NOT require authorization its service account authorization.  If your getting a redirect to login then your using OAUTH2 code.   Follow the tutorial I linked.  **Not** this one [Hello Analytics Reporting API v4; PHP quickstart for web applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php)

Comment: Sorry that was my bad i used the wrong credentials json. Thanks this answered my question.